Are there maps/infographs/pie charts of major source of loanwords in languages?
On WALS, there is a chapter about the spread of the loanword "tea" VS "chai".
I can't find much online except this database which I don't understand the map:
Loanword database
Major source of donor languages is very limited. The biggest donor language today is English. Most donor languages are Indo European languages (Latin Sanskrit Spanish French Greek); others include Arabic, Chinese etc (What are some other major donors?).
I would like a simple list/map/infograph of doner languages and the composite of loanwords in a language:
eg. English (Latin 29%) (French 29%)(Germanic 26%)
English loanwords

The loanword database looks like a great resource I haven't known before. Thanks for sharing!

I am sure there are tons of Indian languages with loanwords that we know nothing about as speakers of Western languages. You probably have to look on sites for the country domain names where languages are spoken.

There is Wiktionary.  The source of words is one of the structured categories.

I wonder how they count variants of words, differing not just in orthography (e.g. organize, organise), but even in pronunciation. Are [seek, seech, beseek, beseech] (native English words) counted as 4 words or 2 words? Are [naïf, naïve] (borrowed from French) counted as 2 words or 1 word?

I think you have to do one language at a time.

@Lambie I know it is very difficult to count precisely and there is no info for smaller languages but it is often obvious what the "major source languages" are and it would be nice to make a map akin to "migration flow chart" "international tourist arrival" and see how few the major donors are/ some unexpected recipients.

First of all,  one normally starts with the language where there are loanwords and then from where. For example: English, loanwords from French, Spanish and Italian. One doesn't usually start with: Italian: loanwords to English. But you could: Italian loanwords TO Spanish, English and Portuguese. It quickly become unwieldy.

Counting the proportion of loanwords can be very tricky because it is hard to define a good base for comparison. Are you interested in the frequency of loanwords in a specific corpus (which gives you lower proportion in general, because many of the function words are inherited) than the genre and the register of the corpus determine it (more loanwords for scientific and more formal corpora). When you base it on a dictionary, again, the choice of the dictionary may change the proportion of loanwords (larger dictionaries probably contain more loanwords).
Even if you restrict yourself to the conditional probability of
P(loanword by source|loanword) 

the relative proportion may vary according to choice of corpus or dictionary.
So getting at numbers of this kind is not that easy, and you should vet your sources on what they mean. Don't trust tabular compilations without a second look at them.

To see some of the complexities involved, see the analysis for Slovak (in Slovak) here (includes the distilled results you are asking for). The raw (manually annotated by the source language(s)) data are here. This gives the borrowings in a corpus, for most frequent words.
See also the followup here (p. 76, by different author) for a better mathematical model.
Disclaimer: I am the author of the former article.

May I suggest replacing the anchor texts "here" by something meaningful, e.g., Author-year of the work, or even better, Author, year and title?
